# Nodejs read a file from an express web page

Tags: node.js, synchronization

i have a problem, I need to read a csv file from a web page developed using express.

Basically I have

```
router.get('/metricas', function(req, res, next) {
  var datos= lee.leedatos();
  res.render('metricas', {page:'Metricas', menuId:'metricas',data:datos});
});
```

and the lee.leedatos() is the following

```
exports.leedatos= function(){
    var datos;
    const csv =require('fast-csv')
    const stream =fs.createReadStream('mywebsite/book1.csv');
    const streamCsv=csv({
        headers:true,

    })
    .on('data',data=>{
        datos=data;
        //console.log(datos);
    })
    .on('finish',()=>{
        console.log('finished')
        console.log(datos)
        return datos;
    })
    stream.pipe(streamCsv);

}
```

My problem is that the web page always returns before the file has been read at all :( .. and data:datos is always empty.

How can I make the call syncronous?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either callbacks / promises to track execution of asynchronous code. This is how code would look like with promises:

```
router.get('/metricas', function(req, res, next) {
  var datos= lee.leedatos().then(() => {
      res.render('metricas', {page:'Metricas', menuId:'metricas',data:datos});
  });
});

exports.leedatos = function () {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var datos;
    const csv = require('fast-csv')
    const stream = fs.createReadStream('mywebsite/book1.csv');
    const streamCsv = csv({
      headers: true,
    }).on('data', data => {
      datos = data;
      //console.log(datos);
    }).on('finish', () => {
      console.log('finished')
      console.log(datos)
      resolve(datos);
    })
    stream.pipe(streamCsv);
  })
}
```

Here is a link to blog post that might help you in understanding asynchronous functions: https://blog.risingstack.com/node-hero-async-programming-in-node-js/

Comment: Thanks a lot !!! I've struggling with this for days ... thanks for the info, now I have a better understanding of asyn nodejs !!